# Is XPath suitable for HTML5 format?

Tags: html, xpath

We know that XPath is created for XML parsing. What about HTML5 since it doesn't necessarily respect XML rules?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are 2 XMLs: Lexical XML and Parsed XML. XPath works against a Parsed XML representation, such as DOM or [XDM](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-datamodel/). You can therefore create Parsed XML from Lexical HTML5, that way you can query HTML5 using XPath.

Answer (score 2):

You can with the huge caveat that you probably shouldn't unless you have too.

Take the following HTML:

```
<div>
    <p> Here is a paragraph
    <p> Here is another, is it inside the first, who knows?
</div>
```

Now most HTML parsers will accept that the above means this:

```
<div>
    <p> Here is a paragraph </p>
    <p> And another, is it inside the first, who knows? </p>
</div>
```

Now, the XPath `/div/p[2]` should return `"And another..."` however, it could equally be interpretted as:

```
<div>
    <p> Here is a paragraph
        <p> And another, is it inside the first, who knows? </p>
    </p>
</div>
```

Where `/div/p[2]` returns nothing and the XPath `/div/p/p` returns `"And another..."` .

HTML isn't XML and doesn't need to be well-formed, so using XML technologies with HTML can lead to idiosyncracies. So as long as you acknowledge those you should be ok.

Answer (score 1):

XPath is for *querying a DOM*, not parsing markup. A DOM can be generated from an HTML document, so you can query it with XPath.

Comment: XPath, the XML Path Language, is a query language for selecting nodes from an XML document. [Wikipedia] : .not any dom then !

Comment: Technically, XPath is not defined to operate against a DOM, but against its own data model, which in XPath 2.0 is called XDM. There's a simple mapping defined from XML to XDM, but it's also possible to define a mapping from HTML5 to XDM. There's no standard mapping defined for this, but for the most part it's fairly obvious.

Comment: @MichaelKay - What do you mean by "fairly obvious"? The mapping from the HTML serialization of HTML5 to DOM is not obvious at all. Do you mean the mapping from a HTML serialization sourced DOM4 API to XDM is "fairly obvious"?

Comment: I mean that the likely way of mapping HTML5 to XDM is essentially the composition of the mapping of HTML5 to DOM and the mapping of DOM to XDM, and is fairly obvious to someone familiar with those two mappings.